# @@DBTS and BInaryFormatter

Tags: t-sql, microsoft-sync-framework, binaryformatter

I have written a client that uses the SyncFramework to coordinate the consolidating of data in a hub and spoke architecture warehousing application.
When the sync transactions process the sync framework updates a specified anchor table with the value of @@DBTS, indicating when the last sync was processed and uploaded to the server.
I would like to offer as part of this scenario the ability to allow one client to relay the data on behalf of one of the others.

This would be used in cases where one client may not be able to make contact with the warehouse; its database could be retrieved and synchronized by a client that does have access to the warehouse (Exchanged as a database backup on DVD or USB flash media).

The problem with this theory is that without the SentAnchor being set on the client database when the snapshot is retrieved, the next time this process is performed, the whole database is replicated in a second time.

What I would like to do, is when I grab a snapshot of the client database, update its SentAnchor so the next time I grab a copy the sync framework will know its SentAnchor *as if* it had actually communicated with the server.

So my first impulse was to simply update the anchor table, set the SentAnchor to @@DBTS, however the problem with that is sync framework inserts the same value in a different format, it runs it through the BinaryFormatter first.

So same intrinsic value, different headers, and when I try just updating with the value of @@DBTS, the SyncFramework errors trying to convert that back from the format it anticipates to have set itself.

What I would like to do is set via a TSQL statement, the same format for @@DBTS that the sync framework uses; I do not want to have to write an application to execute a single SQL statement if this can be done in the statement already being executed to create the backup.

Something like...

```
USE MyDB 
GO 
BACKUP DATABASE MyDb 
TO DISK = 'F:\01032012MyDb.bak'
    WITH FORMAT,    
    NAME = '20120103 Full Backup of MyDb' 
GO 
UPDATE Anchor SET SentAnchor = @@DBTS 
GO
```

Essentially replacing @@DBTS above with whatever is needed to get the same value into the correct fromat that the SyncFramework will use.

Servers are 2008R2 Express.

Answer (score 3):

the problem with setting the SentAnchor is that you might actually miss uploading changes. by setting the value, you have effectively told Sync Framework it has sent changes up to that value of @@DBTS.

i suggest you explore using the SqlSyncProvider instead.

Comment: Yes, it almost parallels the other question I recently posted concerning purging after a backup. Changes may have occurred betwixt backing up and setting this value.
The problem is that this system was not designed for offline sync, and I am trying to reverse engineer a method by which to make it happen without jacking up the stabile systems that work online.
I am rethinking the project as a whole, I will post back if future concerns relate back to this,  thank you for the comment.